# Kernel Compilation error Samsung Galaxy S5 G-900FD

Tags: android, compiler-errors, android-ndk, kernel, galaxy

I've been trying to compile kernel from Samsung source for last few weeks but failed every time.

At start everything goes fine almost. The problem is with the last step of compilation of the kernel. 
Whenever I run the command:

> make -j5

it comes up with  the error:

> scripts/kconfig/conf --silentoldconfig Kconfig
>   sound/soc/codecs/audience/Kconfig:40:warning: type of
>   'SND_SOC_ES_SLIM' redefined from 'boolean' to 'tristate'
>   sound/soc/codecs/audience/Kconfig:43:warning: type of 'SND_SOC_ES_I2C'
>   redefined from 'boolean' to 'tristate' boolean symbol SND_SOC_MAX98506
>   tested for 'm'? test forced to 'n'
>   sound/soc/codecs/audience/Kconfig:44:warning: choice value used
>   outside its choice group sound/soc/codecs/audience/Kconfig:41:warning:
>   choice value used outside its choice group   CHK
>   include/linux/version.h   CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
>   make[1]: 'include/generated/mach-types.h' is up to date.   CC
>   arch/arm/kernel/asm-offsets.s In file included from
>   include/linux/scatterlist.h:10:0,
>                    from include/linux/dma-mapping.h:9,
>                    from arch/arm/kernel/asm-offsets.c:15:   /media/sf_Krnl/Kernel/arch/arm/include/asm/io.h:30:26: fatal error:
>   mach/msm_rtb.h: No such file or directory  #include 
>                             ^ compilation terminated. /media/sf_Krnl/Kernel/./Kbuild:81: recipe for target
>   'arch/arm/kernel/asm-offsets.s' failed make[1]: ***
>   [arch/arm/kernel/asm-offsets.s] Error 1 Makefile:999: recipe for
>   target 'prepare0' failed make: *** [prepare0] Error 2

I've tried it a lot of times by changing directories, folder and terminals but nothing worked.

Further, I've used all these toolchains I mentioned here:

```
UBER Toolchian 7 (arm-eabi)
UBER toolchian 4.9 (arm-eabi)
NDK 4.9 (arm-eabi)
Sabermod 4.9 (arm-eabi)
linaro 4.9 (arm-eabi)
```

but all failed. 
Help me please.